# How to print Element as correct xml with xml tag?

Tags: python, django

So I have this function in my view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

def helloworld(request):
    root_element = Element("root_element")
    comment = Comment("Hello World!!!")
    root_element.append(comment)
    foo_element = Element("foo")
    foo_element.text = "bar"
    bar_element = Element("bar")
    bar_element.text = "foo"
    root_element.append(foo_element)
    root_element.append(bar_element)
    return HttpResponse(tostring(root_element), "application/xml")
```

What it does it prints something like this:

```
<root_element><!--Hello World!!!--><foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar></root_element>
```

As you can see, it is missing the xml tag at the beginning. How to output proper XML beginning with xml declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can add a dependency in your project, I suggest you to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring) which is more complete and optimized than the basic xml module that come with Python.

For doing this, you just have to change your import statement to :

```
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
```

And then, you'll have a tostring() with a 'xml_declaration' option :

```
>>> tostring(root, xml_declaration=False)
'<root_element><!--Hello World!!!--><foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar></root_element>'
>>> tostring(root, xml_declaration=True)
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>\n<root_element><!--Hello World!!!--><foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar></root_element>"
```

In the standard lib, only the write() method of ElementTree have a xml_declaration option. An other solution would be to create a wrapper which use ElementTree.write() to write into a StringIO and then, to return the content of the StringIO.